# Headless Chrome Doesn't work With head works

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I have a functional version that has a head on the selenium chrome driver. But when I try without head (headless) it just goes to the catch for some reason.

Headless Code:

```
        Dim driveroptions As ChromeOptions = New ChromeOptions()
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            driveroptions.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\" + GetUserName() + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
        Else
            driveroptions.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" + TextBox2.Text)
        End If
        driveroptions.AddArgument("--headless")
        Dim service As ChromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
        Dim driver2 As IWebDriver = New ChromeDriver(service, driveroptions)

        Dim UserName_TextBox As IWebElement
        Dim Password_TextBox As IWebElement
        Dim No_Save_Password As IWebElement

        If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
            Try
                driver2.Navigate().GoToUrl("url")
                Thread.Sleep("5000")
                driver2.SwitchTo.Frame(0)
                UserName_TextBox = driver2.FindElement(By.Name("user"))
                UserName_TextBox.Click()
                UserName_TextBox.SendKeys(username)
                driver2.SwitchTo().DefaultContent()
                driver2.SwitchTo().Frame(0)
                Password_TextBox = driver2.FindElement(By.Name("password"))
                Password_TextBox.Click()
                Password_TextBox.SendKeys(password)
                Password_TextBox.Submit()
                driver2.SwitchTo().DefaultContent()
                driver2.SwitchTo().Frame(0)
                Thread.Sleep(3500)
                No_Save_Password = driver2.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#modal > div > div > div > div.pill-wrap.double > a:nth-child(1)"))
                No_Save_Password.Click()
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
                driver2.Quit()

            Catch ex As Exception
               ''do error stuff here
            End Try
```

Comment: What's the exception

Comment: I just make it add +1 to a label for errors if it goes to exception part. But it doesnt give any actual errors when i run it

Comment: If an exception is thrown there is an exception message.  *That* code is ignoring it

Comment: how do i find the message?

Comment: You replace "do error stuff" with ACTUAL error stuff